# How to get response session cookie in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, playframework-2.0, session-cookies

I need to get response session cookie in JQuery. I need to know if session has expired and I believe the only way to do is to check whether response from server contains session cookie
I am using play framework in backend which doesnt preserve session details at backend and keep session details in cookie only

I tried to get cookie from the response like this -

```
    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: '@@{search()}',      data:$('#searchForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data, testStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.indexOf("errorsSection") > 0) {
                alert("trying to get access of cookies from response header in if :"+ jqXHR.getResponseHeader("PLAY_SESSION"));
                $('#searchResults').hide();
                $('#errors').html(data);
                $('#errors').show();
            } else {
alert("trying to get access of cookies from response header in else :"+ jqXHR.getResponseHeader("PLAY_SESSION"));
                alert("trying to get access of cookies from response header in else :"+ jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
                alert("in else::::" + $.cookie("PLAY_SESSION") );

                $('#errors').hide();
                $('#searchResults').html(data);
                $('#searchResults').show();}
```

jqXHR.getResponseHeader("PLAY_SESSION") gives back null whereas jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders() give all the header specific data except the data for cookies.

Can you please help me in finding cookie from response?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mohit

Comment: how do you set the cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to check cookie in front-end, and actually you should not to it especially if you care for security.

Your backend action should return [`ok()`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html#ok())  Result in case when everything's ok.

If user is unlogged you can return [`unathorized()`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html#unauthorized()) (`Unathorized()` in Scala).

than in your jQuery you should handle them with `success` or `error` callbacks.

**Edit:** Just answered very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30001885/1066240, actually to get header you need to set them first (cookie is not header)