# Play: Session Cookie not set. Cannot read Cookie using Javascript

Tags: ajax, scala, session, cookies, playframework

In order to send an authorization token (that should be stored in a database) to my server, I do an AJAX call in my .scala.html file.

```
$.ajax({
       url: "http://localhost:9000/storeauthcode",
       type: 'get',
       data: {code: authResult['code']},
       contentType: 'application/json',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(result) {
       // Handle or verify the server response.
           console.log("you're fully logged in now.")
           console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
           console.log("document.cookie = "+document.cookie)
       },
       error: function (xhr, status, error) {
           console.log("error\n")
           console.log(xhr.responseText)
       }

   });
  }
```

On the server side, I store the auth code and return a json response

```
  def storeAuthCode  = Action { request =>
  //store credentials in database
  //...
  //return some data
  Ok(Json.toJson(Map("a"->"b"))).withSession("code"-> "someAuthCode", "id"->"someId")
}
```

If I try to print all cookies in the success handler of my AJAX call via

```
console.log("document.cookie = "+document.cookie)
```

document.cookie seems to be empty although the server should have created a session Cookie (or at least anything). document.cookie should return a ";" separated list of my Cookie values.

How can I set my Cookies successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't read this is [`HTTPOnly`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#Browsers_Supporting_HttpOnly) flag set for Play's session cookie.

You have several options which you can use instead:

1. Send `code` and `id` in the JSON object (like `"a"->"b"`)
2. You can also send them as [`response headers`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaResults#Manipulating-HTTP-headers) so you can get them within your success callback like:

   ```
   Ok(Json.toJson(Map("a" -> "b")))
     .withHeaders(
       "code" -> "foo",
       "id" -> "bar"
     )
     .withCookies(
       Cookie("code", "foo"),
       Cookie("id", "bar")
     )
   ```

   jQuery

   ```
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       console.log(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('code'));
       console.log(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('id'));
   },
   ```